# Eclipse logcat debugging

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, logcat

I have a beginner question, I want to debug my app and i don't know how to use the Logcat properly.

Right now, I am getting this error and i don't know what it means.

How can i use this information?
Is there a tutorial somewhere i can watch?

Thanks for your help.

```
09-23 11:27:55.968: E/AndroidRuntime(807): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 11:27:55.968: E/AndroidRuntime(807): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 11:27:55.968: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at com.uniqueapps.runner.Start.onClick(Start.java:49)
09-23 11:27:55.968: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
09-23 11:27:55.968: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
09-23 11:27:55.968: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-23 11:27:55.968: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-23 11:27:55.968: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-23 11:27:55.968: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-23 11:27:55.968: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 11:27:55.968: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-23 11:27:55.968: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-23 11:27:55.968: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-23 11:27:55.968: E/AndroidRuntime(807):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-23 11:27:59.528: I/Process(807): Sending signal. PID: 807 SIG: 9
09-23 11:28:01.108: D/gralloc_goldfish(877): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-23 11:54:55.318: D/gralloc_goldfish(937): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-23 11:54:57.887: I/Choreographer(937): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-23 11:55:03.118: D/dalvikvm(937): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 89K, 7% free 2928K/3136K, paused 39ms, total 72ms
09-23 11:55:05.858: D/AndroidRuntime(937): Shutting down VM
09-23 11:55:05.858: W/dalvikvm(937): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
09-23 11:55:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 11:55:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 11:55:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.uniqueapps.runner.Start.onClick(Start.java:49)
09-23 11:55:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
09-23 11:55:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
09-23 11:55:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-23 11:55:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-23 11:55:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-23 11:55:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-23 11:55:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 11:55:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-23 11:55:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-23 11:55:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-23 11:55:05.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-23 11:55:09.657: D/gralloc_goldfish(961): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-23 12:04:20.418: D/gralloc_goldfish(1006): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-23 12:04:27.118: D/dalvikvm(1006): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 96K, 7% free 2919K/3136K, paused 40ms, total 72ms
09-23 12:04:30.337: D/AndroidRuntime(1006): Shutting down VM
09-23 12:04:30.357: W/dalvikvm(1006): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
09-23 12:04:30.397: E/AndroidRuntime(1006): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 12:04:30.397: E/AndroidRuntime(1006): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 12:04:30.397: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at com.uniqueapps.runner.Start.onClick(Start.java:49)
09-23 12:04:30.397: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
09-23 12:04:30.397: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
09-23 12:04:30.397: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-23 12:04:30.397: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-23 12:04:30.397: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-23 12:04:30.397: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-23 12:04:30.397: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 12:04:30.397: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-23 12:04:30.397: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-23 12:04:30.397: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-23 12:04:30.397: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-23 12:04:33.918: D/gralloc_goldfish(1030): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Comment: something on line 49 `Start.java` null.

Comment: Give us the code for Start.java

Comment: check in line 49 of Start.java weather some thing is giving null .or post the full code of Start.java

Comment: +1 for asking.  Most beginners, even after you tell them what the problem is and exactly where it is don't have the curiosity to ask this question.  BTW, learn how to use the debugger next.  Logcat is not for debugging (well, sometimes it is but not for beginners).  Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you see

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

you will see the problem, here a `NPE`

```
09-23 11:27:55.968: E/AndroidRuntime(807): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

then you find the first line that references your app. Here it is the following line

```
at com.uniqueapps.runner.Start.onClick(Start.java:49)
```

This says that in `Start.java` something is `null` in `onClick()` at line 49. So you go to that line and see what *could* be `null`...like a variable that tries to access a method such as `setText()`, `getText()`, or any Android or user defined method. Sometimes it is simple why it is `null` and sometimes you have to trace back further to see what makes it `null`.

**Edit**

If a variable is `null` it is because it hasn't been initialized properly, or at all. So maybe you have a variable `TextView tv;` but you never gave it a value by doing something like

```
 tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTV);
```

if you try to do something like `tv.setText("Some Text");` you will get a `NPE` because you didn't initialize it with something like the above line of code. Or maybe you tried to initialize it and used the wrong `id` like one from a different `layout`. This will return `null` and create a `NPE` in the same way. This can be on any variable that you try to call a method on.

Comment: Really great info. When something is null, is that because of misspelling in the code, or is the code simply wrong so it sends a null value?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained that. See my edit to my answer. It means it hasn't been giving a value or it tried and its value is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It says it's NullPointerException at 49 th line on Start.java file.

Logcat allows you to filter you your all logs from left pan. Which is the best thing over there.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this tips to use logcat..

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    System.out.println("1. Before Declare");

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    System.out.println("2. After Declare"); 

}
```

See result on logcat, then you can see your step..