# Android beginner onClick crash

Tags: java, android

I'm programming Android for the first time and I'm having some difficulties. The idea is to make a guessing game app in which the user takes a number in his/her head and the app tries to guess it. The user will give hints like higher and lower to the app. For some reason the app crashes after I press the start button. Because of this, I know that there is an error in the `onClick` method but since it shuts down immediately after I press the start button, I can't use something like a `println` to debug.

So actually I have 2 questions:

1. Where does my reasoning fail? (or show me how to figure out my mistakes)
2. How can I debug things like this?

The start, higher and lower are all buttons in the program.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        int min = 0;
        int max = 100;
        Random random = new Random(100);
        int answer = 0;

        if (arg0 == start) {
            answer = random.nextInt(100);
            buttonTextView.setText(answer);
        }
        else if (arg0 == higher){
            min = answer;
            answer = random.nextInt((max - min) + min);
            buttonTextView.setText(answer);
        }
        else if (arg0 == lower) {
            max = answer;
            answer = random.nextInt((max-1) - min);
            buttonTextView.setText(answer);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can debug using Logcat. Usually a crash will printStackTrace() and you can see exactly where it happened.

Comment: Show us logcat error logs and we can tell exactly which line you have error... (Mostly :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. where does my reasoning fail?

You are using the wrong `setText()` method. [In the TextView Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) you will see that there is one which takes an `int`, this is for retrieving a `String` resource that you have in your `strings.xml` so you would pass it a `resource id`. So your `setText()` is looking for a `resource` with the `id` of whatever your `answer` variable is. You will want to convert this to a `String` with something like

```
buttonTextView.setText(String.valueof(answer));
```

or one of several different ways.

> 2. How can I debug things like this?

When your app crashes there will be an exception in your logcat. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964329/eclipse-logcat-debugging/18964524#18964524) can help you to read your logcat. To open your logcat window in Eclipse, if it isn't already, you can do this

> Window --> Show View --> Other --> Android --> LogCat

**A couple side notes**

You should change your `params` like in `onClick()` to something meaningful so I would change

```
public void onClick(View arg0)
```

to something like

```
public void onClick(View v)  // v for view, could also be view, btn
                       //  whatever makes sense to you and others who may read it
```

You also should compare the `id` of your `View` clicked instead of the `View` itself. So you would compare it with something like the following (assuming you changed `arg0` to `v`)

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.start)  // Assuming start is the id in your xml of your Button
                                 // this will also allow you to use a switch statement
```

Your variables in `onClick()` (`min`, `max`, and `answer`) should be initialized outside of `onClick()` or they will be reset to the default values with each click which I'm pretty sure you don't want (thanks to 323go for pointing that out).

Comment: Might want to give him a hint that `answer` won't be available on subsequent clicks, unless he puts the member in the Activity scope or makes it static.

Comment: @323go I'm not sure what you mean. What do you mean it won't be "available"?

Comment: He's using the local variable `answer` to calculate a new answer based on higher/lower button presses. He won't have the previous value of `answer` on subsequent invocations of `onClick`, and it will always be 0.

Comment: @323go Don't you mean `min` and `max` because those would be reset each time

Comment: Ok, yes, I hadn't gotten into the logic just what was wrong with the syntax. All 3 variables should be member variables and not initialized in the `onClick()`

Comment: All three, actually. `min`, `max` and `answer`.