# Android - Getting a Null Pointer Exception running a ListView extending a BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, baseadapter

I'm working on an android application and I can not understand why I keep on getting a null pointer exception in this class.  I have a listview and a base adapter and I think my code is correct, but obviously not.  I need help on fixing this issue and will appreciate all the help given. Below is the logcat error and the java code.

```
10-20 00:17:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(24078): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-20 00:17:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(24078): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-20 00:17:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(24078):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
10-20 00:17:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(24078):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-20 00:17:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(24078):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-20 00:17:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(24078):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-20 00:17:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(24078):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-20 00:17:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(24078):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-20 00:17:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(24078):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-20 00:17:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(24078):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-20 00:17:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(24078):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
10-20 00:17:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(24078): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-20 00:17:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(24078):    at **com.creation.joopn.VListActivity$LoadVenues.doInBackground(VListActivity.java:150)
10-20 00:17:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(24078):    at com.creation.joopn.VListActivity$LoadVenues.doInBackground(VListActivity.java:1)**
10-20 00:17:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(24078):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-20 00:17:39.342: E/AndroidRuntime(24078):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Class

```
public class VListActivity extends Activity {

    TextView name;
    String my_id, my_type;
    ListView list;
    VListAdapter adapter;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> venueList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String Venue_URL = "http://www.createinv.com/list/myVenues.php";

    // JSON Node names
    static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    static final String KEY_VENUES = "venues";
    static final String KEY_ID = "venue_id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "venue_name";
    static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "street";
    static final String KEY_CITY = "city";
    static final String KEY_STATE = "state";
    static final String KEY_ZIP = "zip";
    static final String KEY_NUMBER = "phone_number";
    static final String KEY_BIO = "bio";

    JSONArray venues = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        SharedPreferences sp = 
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        my_id = sp.getString("my_id", null);
        my_type = sp.getString("my_type", null);

        new LoadVenues().execute(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    class LoadVenues extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VListActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Venues. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("my_id", my_id));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("my_type", my_type));
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(Venue_URL, "POST", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Venues: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of venues
                    venues = json.getJSONArray(KEY_VENUES);

                    // looping through All venues
                    venueList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < venues.length(); i++) {

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject c = venues.getJSONObject(i);

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(KEY_ID, c.getString(KEY_ID));
                        map.put(KEY_NAME, c.getString(KEY_NAME));
                        map.put(KEY_ADDRESS, c.getString(KEY_ADDRESS));
                        map.put(KEY_CITY, c.getString(KEY_CITY).concat(", "));
                        map.put(KEY_STATE, c.getString(KEY_STATE));
                        map.put(KEY_ZIP, c.getString(KEY_ZIP));
                        map.put(KEY_NUMBER, c.getString(KEY_NUMBER));

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        venueList.add(map);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) { 
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    adapter = new VListAdapter(VListActivity.this, venueList);
                    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);       
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public class VListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private Context context;

        public VListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> venueList){

            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.context = context;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return venueList.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_homelist, null);

            TextView venue_id = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.venue_id);
            TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView address = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.address1);
            TextView city = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.city);
            TextView state = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.state);
            TextView zip = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.zip);
            TextView number = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.phnumber);

            HashMap<String, String> vlist = new HashMap<String, String>();
            vlist = venueList.get(position);

            // Setting all values in listview
            venue_id.setText(vlist.get(VListActivity.KEY_ID));
            name.setText(vlist.get(VListActivity.KEY_NAME));
            name.setOnClickListener(new myOnClickListener(position));
            address.setText(vlist.get(VListActivity.KEY_ADDRESS));
            city.setText(vlist.get(VListActivity.KEY_CITY));
            state.setText(vlist.get(VListActivity.KEY_STATE));
            zip.setText(vlist.get(VListActivity.KEY_ZIP));
            number.setText(vlist.get(VListActivity.KEY_NUMBER));

            return vi;
        }

        public class myOnClickListener implements OnClickListener{
            private int position;
            public myOnClickListener(int position){
                this.position=position;
            }
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                HashMap<String, String> update = new HashMap<String, String>();
                update = venueList.get(position); 
                Log.d("Testing Click", update.get(VListActivity.KEY_ID));

                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(VListActivity.this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
                edit.putString("venue_id", update.get(VListActivity.KEY_ID));
                edit.commit();

                Intent in = new Intent(VListActivity.this, VenueProfileActivity.class); 
                startActivity(in);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is at line 150 of `VListActivity`? Something there is `null`

Comment: I don't understand why it is so hard to read a NullPointer exception.   It tells you the exact line in the code.

Comment: @Booger it is not hard for people that know how to read it. For people who are new to development they may just need a little guidance to understand what it all means.

Comment: Line 150 is getting the zipcode, but that textview is there

Comment: Even if I comment that line out I get a null pointer exception at line 175: list.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Line 150: map.put(KEY_ZIP, c.getString(KEY_ZIP));

Comment: Are you sure that's the line? If so try cleaning your project. In Eclipse, "Project --> Clean...". That would mean that `map` or `c` is `null` which the `NPE` would be thrown earlier if so and `map` isn't `null`.

Comment: Also, remove `runOnUiThread(new Runnable()` from `onPostExecute()` since that method already runs on the `UI Thread`

Comment: Ok, I cleaned and removed and the result is:10-20 00:48:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(25700): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-20 00:48:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(25700):  at com.creation.joopn.VListActivity$LoadVenues.onPostExecute(VListActivity.java:172)
10-20 00:48:00.792: E/AndroidRuntime(25700):  at com.creation.joopn.VListActivity$LoadVenues.onPostExecute(VListActivity.java:1)
and Line 172 is list.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Is `list` the `id` of a `ListView` in `activity_list.xml`?

Comment: @codeMagic Yes it is
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="#dddddd"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" >

    </ListView>

  </LinearLayout>

Comment: See my answer. That should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `ListView` in your `layout` file to look like this

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" <!-- change the id like this -->
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:divider="#dddddd" 
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" > </ListView>
```

The way you have it would work if you were extending `ListActivity` but since you are just extending `Activity` you don't need to declare the `id` that way. You just give it your own `id`.

The original problem seems that the project just needed to be cleaned with "Project --> Clean..." then run the project again since the `NPE` didn't make sense with the given code. Also, `runOnUiThread` isn't needed and shouldn't be used in `onPostExecute()` since that method already runs on the `UI Thread`.

Comment: You're welcome and +1 for a well-formed question. You may want to look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964329/eclipse-logcat-debugging/18964524#18964524) about reading logcat. It may help you to do a little more initial error-finding for yourself, although this one was a little more tricky since the project needed to be cleaned to find the real error.

Comment: Yeah, this is my first android project and I've been having a heck of a time

Comment: See that answer then, it should really help. Just one more bit of advice, when you put code in a comment (which you don't want to do to much of, instead edit your post and add it if its more than a line or two) format it so its easier for people to read. Just add a "`" before and after the code or highlight it and press "CTRL+K". Welcome to Android development and SO.

Comment: I have another issue, is there a way I can send you an email?

Comment: No but give it a try and if you have trouble post a question