# NullPointerException while fetching current GPS

Tags: android, gps, location, alarmmanager

I have a test screen where there is a button - where it is pressed it calls the service. I'm trying to implement a way to get the current gps location of the current user and it is crashing when it tries to call. Can anyone tell what the problem is?

```
package com.example.whereyouapp;

import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Controller extends Service{

private static final int POLL_INTERVAL = 1000 *3;

static int number_of_times=0;

Location location;
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
      makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

public void makeUseOfNewLocation(Location location){
    this.location=location;
}

public static double coordinatesDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2){//returns distance in kilometers between two coordiantes
    double deltaLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double deltaLong = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
    lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
    lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);
    double a = Math.sin(deltaLat / 2) * Math.sin(deltaLat / 2) + Math.sin(deltaLong / 2) * Math.sin(deltaLong / 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
    double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
    return 6371 * c; 
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId){
    Toast.makeText(this, "yololo- the service class works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //sendSMS("5613500110","If you received this text message then the Service class for WhereYouApp works");

            // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
                 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 0, locationListener);

            if(location!=null){
            double distance=coordinatesDistance(location.getLatitude(),location.getLatitude(),location.getLatitude()+2,location.getLatitude()+2);

            Toast.makeText(this, ""+distance, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

    if(number_of_times==5){
        setServiceAlarm(getBaseContext(),false);
        number_of_times=-1;
    }
    number_of_times++;
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "yolo- the service has stopped working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
    values.put("address", phoneNumber); 
    values.put("body", message); 
    getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
}

public static void setServiceAlarm(Context context, boolean isOn){

        Intent i = new Intent(context, Controller.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager =        (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (isOn) {
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis(), POLL_INTERVAL, pi);
        } else {
            alarmManager.cancel(pi);
            pi.cancel();
        }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
 }
```

This class will be used to test controller functions, it will consist of a screen with buttons that do various functions

```
package com.example.whereyouapp;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ControllerTestingScreen extends Activity{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_controller_test_screen);
    //Set button colors to red, green, blue, and red, respectively
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testbutton);
    button.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    OnClickListener buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Controller.setServiceAlarm(getBaseContext(), true);
        }
    };
    button.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
}
}
```

Logcat:

```
    02-26 22:04:38.317: D/AndroidRuntime(1427): Shutting down VM
02-26 22:04:38.317: W/dalvikvm(1427): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a91ba8)
02-26 22:04:38.457: D/dalvikvm(1427): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 115K, 6% free 3270K/3460K, paused 87ms, total 103ms
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427): Process: com.example.whereyouapp, PID: 1427
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.example.whereyouapp.Controller: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2556)
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:540)
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at com.example.whereyouapp.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:30)
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2553)
02-26 22:04:38.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     ... 10 more
02-26 22:04:45.187: I/Process(1427): Sending signal. PID: 1427 SIG: 9
02-26 22:04:47.507: D/AndroidRuntime(1469): Shutting down VM
02-26 22:04:47.507: W/dalvikvm(1469): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a91ba8)
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469): Process: com.example.whereyouapp, PID: 1469
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.example.whereyouapp.Controller: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2556)
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:540)
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at com.example.whereyouapp.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:30)
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2553)
02-26 22:04:47.517: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: Have you given permission in Manifest file ?

Comment: The logcat is so clear at com.example.whereyouapp.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:30) what was the question, why was the question ? How is anyone to know where line 30 is ?

Comment: Wow...tough crowd! Sid probably edited while yours was pending, Ked (just my guess).

Comment: Rejected by Community♦ so, yeah probably.

Comment: Let's all take a step back. It's just an edit...not worth fighting about. @Kedarnath you can see who approved/rejected your edits by clicking on the "suggestions" tab in your profile and click on the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some changes in your code and finally got a working code.

```
public class Controller extends Service 
{
    private static final int POLL_INTERVAL = 1000 *3;
    static int number_of_times=0;

    Location currentLocation;
    static LocationManager locationManager;
    // Define a listener that responds to location updates

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() 
    {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
        {
            currentLocation = location;
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };


    public static double coordinatesDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2)
    {
        //returns distance in kilometers between two coordiantes
        double deltaLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
        double deltaLong = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
        lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
        lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);
        double a = Math.sin(deltaLat / 2) * Math.sin(deltaLat / 2) + Math.sin(deltaLong / 2) * Math.sin(deltaLong / 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
        double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
        return 6371 * c; 
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "yololo- the service class works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //sendSMS("5613500110","If you received this text message then the Service class for WhereYouApp works");

        if ( locationManager != null )
        {
            System.out.println ( "not null" );
            // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        }

        if( currentLocation != null )
        {
            double distance=coordinatesDistance(currentLocation.getLatitude(),currentLocation.getLatitude(),currentLocation.getLatitude()+2,currentLocation.getLatitude()+2);
            Toast.makeText(this, ""+distance, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println  ( "location not found" );
        }

        if(number_of_times==5)
        {
            setServiceAlarm(getBaseContext(),false);
            number_of_times=-1;
        }
        number_of_times++;
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "yolo- the service has stopped working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) 
    {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
        values.put("address", phoneNumber); 
        values.put("body", message); 
        getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
    }

    public static void setServiceAlarm(Context context, boolean isOn)
    {
        // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Controller.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (isOn) 
        {
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(), POLL_INTERVAL, pi);
        } 
        else 
        {
            alarmManager.cancel(pi);
            pi.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This code perfectly runs on my Samsung device.

Comment: What is the point of locationListenerGps.onLocationChanged(currentLocation);

Comment: It is your lastKnownPosition location.

Comment: I deleted this line from the code and nothing changed. Why?

Comment: I deleted it just to see what happened

Comment: So, what i'm not understanding is why would you call the locationListenerGps.onLocationChanged(currentLocation); and pass in the currentlocation and then set the currentlocation to location.Wouldn't this be redundant because the location is set in getlastKnownlocation?

Comment: Ok, that's my mistake. Yesterday your question created a lot tension in my head. Its long story. But yes you can omit that line. Code will work fine without that line as well.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a `NPE` on this line

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

because your `Context` is `null` since the `Service` hasn't actually been created yet. Move that line inside `onStartCommand()`.

Much like an `Activity`, there is no `Context` until it has been started. With an `Activity`, not before `onCreate()` has run and, with a `Service`, it wouldn't be available until `onCreate()` or `onStartCommand()`.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964329/eclipse-logcat-debugging/18964524#18964524) on how to read your logcat. It will take you a long way.

Comment: It still gives me errors with the locationManager inside the Service

Comment: That's terrible but, without knowing what errors, I have no way of helping. Unless I want to spend the rest of the night going through your code (which I don't) ;) But I believe your initial problem is solved.

Comment: Please, don't leave comments like that. I want to help but that makes me want to help much less...it is very unhelpful. What would be helpful is posting the errors you get. Oh, and by looking at the link I posted which shows how to read your logcat. That is very important if you want to be a developer.

Comment: I don't have gps on my emulator so it gives an error, so I can't tell what the problem is. It still crashes on my phone though...

Comment: Debug on your phone. Much easier and faster than an emulator. I really can't help without knowing what the error is and I'm not going to go through every line of your code and guess what the problem is.

Comment: I don't have the connector to my phone...so I can't debug on my phone

Comment: Go buy one, they are really cheap. And I *still* can't help until you get the errors. You got your logcat once already.

Comment: Hmmm...you should go to where it is

Comment: I haven't used genymotion but a dear friend told me to tell you to download it because it has gps. Thanks, neb!

Comment: @user35265, seriously ?