# How to get latitude and longitude offline in android ?

Tags: android, gps

I want to get current location (latitude & longitude) , when WiFi & Gps is off .It is possible to get latitude and longitude from mobile sim network. I searched more on google but i did not get satisfies answers.

Answer (score 2):

From my yesterday's experience on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22058169/3330969), I finally found out that it is impossible to fetch latitude longitude's value without Internet connection in device. ( Gosh I spent 3 hours to find why my running code working properly. ) Even to get the value from `getLastKnowLocation()` you must require Internet connection.

Comment: @user3363194 You welcome. You may accept my answer by ticking green tick mark besides my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
 LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(location==null){
        location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is impossible. While you can store cell tower ID's to know when you're close to an area you've been in before, you can't actually use these values to get latitude and longitude numbers (Well, unless you stored some lat and long values and paired them with that cell tower).  You can however call `getLastKnownLocation()` to... get the last known location from the GPS or Wifi.

**Edit**

Apparently google has built a database of lat/long with cellID's already. It is not part of the standard Android API, and requires a network connection to hit.  Pretty cool though.  [You can find more at this (really slow) website](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40524/0/page/2)

Comment: Thanks for giving me your time

Comment: Many apps work offline (without internet) and does NOT use mobile GPS to show longitude-latitude information from location/address. I do not know how they work? Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: example app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vishdroid.jyotisha