# There is any way to get Location address using latitude and longitude offline(Without Internet) mode?

Tags: android, geolocation

```
private String getCompleteAddressString(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE) 
    {
         String strAdd = "";
         Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
     try {
             List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
             if (addresses != null) 
             {
                 Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                 StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");

                 for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) 
                 {
                     strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                 }
                 strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
                 Log.w("My Current loction address", "" + strReturnedAddress.toString());
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Address :" +strAdd, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             } 
             else 
             {
                 Log.w("My Current loction address", "No Address returned!");
             }
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             Log.w("My Current loction address", "Canont get Address!");
         }
         return strAdd;
     }
```

This is my code but it requires Internet Connection.. when i run this without internet connection it throws Exception server time-out.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get latitude and longitude offline without internet. You can get it by network, gps or `location.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)` (without internet).

See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22085632/3864698. Maybe it can help you.

Comment: i have already get latitude and longitude using network provider but i have require that latitude and longitude location address..??

Comment: Use Geocoder. You can get  street address, city, a country of the address etc. there.
List<Address> addr = geocoder.getFromLocation(mLatitude, mLongitude, 1) and then getMaxAddressLineIndex(), getLocality(), getCountryName() from first item in List.

Answer (score 0):

Since i must not comment with my reputation, sorry for not providing a real answer i guess:
What you describe is exactly the expected behaviour, according to the documentation of Geocoder:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation%28double,%20double,%20int%29

If you want to handle that case differently, can't you just catch that IO exception explicitly?

If you really want to get a valid address, you can only mirror the relevant lat, long in an offline DB - something i would not recommend.