# How google map fetching address even android device is offline

Tags: android, google-maps, android-permissions, google-maps-api-2

I just created a map activity with some markers and while click on marker title fetching address of marked position for educational purpose,Everything works fine.

It's fetching address even if device is not connected to internet. I didn't given internet permission in manifest. 
`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is the only permission given to the app.

**My Question is:** How application able to get address even device is in offline mode? What's the idea or technology behind it!!?

**Nb:** *I never used `getLastKnownLocation` method in my code. Both Wifi and gps off and no sim card inserted.*

Here is my code :

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    TextView mapPosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        mapPosition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textplace);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
       // double lat = Double.valueOf(8.524139);
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151); LatLng ind = new LatLng(8.524139, 76.936638);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ind).title("Marker in Trivandrum"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ind));

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {






                return false;
            }
        });

    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            Geocoder geocoder;
            List<Address> addresses;
            geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());

            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(marker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude, 1);

                // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5

                String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
                String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
                String countrycode = addresses.get(0).getCountryCode();

                mapPosition.setText(""+ address);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    }
}
```

Comment: so you are saying that Google's `Maps` app can work without online access and can find address, show maps, find a route between 2 points etc?

Comment: i didn't check routes, but map works fine without internet.

Comment: we are talking about the address, right? like `10 Downing St, Westminster, London SW1A 2AA, UK`, and not `51.503396°N 0.127640°W`

Comment: I'm passing lat and long then receiving address. lat and lng are hardcoded.

Comment: so move your location from *Thiruvananthapuram* to some other distant place like *tokyo* / *paris*  / whatever and try again

Comment: new LatLng(35.685360, 139.753372); doesn't getting address but marker placed at map and still viewing without network access.

Comment: so you have the answer that it cannot simply work - you cannot get address when your device is offline - all you had before are cached (estimated) results

Comment: so the map is also cached right?

Comment: yes: did you try to use google's `Maps` app when offline? does it work? of course not - what it can do is to cache some small recently used area, not the whole world

Comment: Ok thanks , now i got it. Appreciate your patience too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be cached memory is the answer . I have checked first time with internet, So app stores it cache thats why i still get map loading and getting address of the same lat and lng in device offline.

Code mentioned in the question works fine. Thanks to @pskink.

Answer (score 1):

You can get latitude and longitude it by network, gps or location.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) (without internet).

See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22085632/3864698. Maybe it can help you.

and then from latitude and longitude you can get full address using geocoder class as :

```
    Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5

String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
```

Comment: My code works fine and i'm able to get address. Whats the idea behind it. I never used {getLastKnownLocation} in my code. Wifi, gps, internet is off and no sim card inserted.

Comment: they could get language using geocode class that work offline

Comment: That means geocoder works  without help of any of these gps, wifi and internet ?

Comment: yes but only need latitude and longitude that we can also get offline using network, wifi.