# AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: main amongst many other errors

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to make the Endurance button on the Exercise List Page launch Endurance list.  The Warmups button works fine.  But, the endurance button makes the app crash when clicked.  Here is the Exercise List Java:

```
    package com.example.chopbuilderfordrums;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ExerciseList extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button button1;
    Button button2;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise_list);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void button1Click()
    {
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.chopbuilderfordrums.LaunchWarmupsList"     ));    
    }

    private void button2Click()
    {
        startActivity(new     Intent("com.example.chopbuilderfordrums.LaunchEnduranceList" ));  
    }
    public void onClick (View v) {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.button1:
            button1Click();
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
                button2Click();
                break;  
        }

    }




}
```

Here are the errors that come up when button is pressed:

```
03-23 16:18:36.056: D/dalvikvm(1541): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
03-23 16:18:41.536: D/gralloc_goldfish(1541): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-23 16:18:47.766: I/Choreographer(1541): Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-23 16:26:41.666: I/Choreographer(1541): Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-23 16:26:52.336: I/Choreographer(1541): Skipped 119 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-23 16:26:52.636: D/dalvikvm(1541): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 119K, 6% free 3263K/3452K, paused 272ms, total 286ms
03-23 16:37:32.486: D/gralloc_goldfish(1613): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-23 17:05:05.426: D/gralloc_goldfish(1670): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-23 17:05:08.246: D/dalvikvm(1670): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 75K, 5% free 3235K/3380K, paused 75ms, total 80ms
03-23 17:05:08.356: D/dalvikvm(1670): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 7K, 5% free 3326K/3480K, paused 67ms, total 68ms
03-23 17:05:08.376: I/dalvikvm-heap(1670): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.389MB for 1127536-byte allocation
03-23 17:05:08.436: D/dalvikvm(1670): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 4427K/4584K, paused 51ms, total 51ms
03-23 17:33:21.006: D/gralloc_goldfish(1721): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-23 17:33:24.376: D/dalvikvm(1721): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 79K, 5% free 3234K/3384K, paused 78ms, total 87ms
03-23 17:33:24.436: D/dalvikvm(1721): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 7K, 5% free 3326K/3484K, paused 48ms, total 49ms
03-23 17:33:24.466: I/dalvikvm-heap(1721): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.389MB for 1127536-byte allocation
03-23 17:33:24.526: D/dalvikvm(1721): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 4426K/4588K, paused 54ms, total 54ms
03-23 17:33:36.946: I/Choreographer(1721): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-23 17:34:23.676: I/Choreographer(1721): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-23 17:34:25.736: I/Choreographer(1721): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-23 17:36:25.806: D/gralloc_goldfish(1786): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-23 17:36:28.826: D/dalvikvm(1786): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 83K, 5% free 3234K/3388K, paused 81ms, total 89ms
03-23 17:36:28.916: D/dalvikvm(1786): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 5% free 3331K/3488K, paused 63ms, total 64ms
03-23 17:36:28.926: I/dalvikvm-heap(1786): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.395MB for 1127536-byte allocation
03-23 17:36:28.986: D/dalvikvm(1786): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 4% free 4427K/4592K, paused 45ms, total 45ms
03-23 17:36:42.046: I/Choreographer(1786): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-23 17:54:38.296: I/Choreographer(1786): Skipped 228 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-23 18:10:19.436: D/gralloc_goldfish(1841): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-23 18:10:21.866: D/AndroidRuntime(1841): Shutting down VM
03-23 18:10:21.866: W/dalvikvm(1841): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a43b90)
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841): Process: com.example.chopbuilderfordrums, PID: 1841
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.chopbuilderfordrums.LaunchEnduranceList }
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3423)
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3384)
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3626)
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3594)
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at com.example.chopbuilderfordrums.ExerciseList.button2Click(ExerciseList.java:32)
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at com.example.chopbuilderfordrums.ExerciseList.onClick(ExerciseList.java:42)
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-23 18:10:21.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-23 18:10:29.176: I/Process(1841): Sending signal. PID: 1841 SIG: 9
03-23 18:10:46.296: D/gralloc_goldfish(1874): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-23 18:10:48.526: D/AndroidRuntime(1874): Shutting down VM
03-23 18:10:48.526: W/dalvikvm(1874): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a43b90)
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874): Process: com.example.chopbuilderfordrums, PID: 1874
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.chopbuilderfordrums.LaunchEnduranceList }
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3423)
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3384)
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3626)
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3594)
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at com.example.chopbuilderfordrums.ExerciseList.button2Click(ExerciseList.java:32)
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at com.example.chopbuilderfordrums.ExerciseList.onClick(ExerciseList.java:42)
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-23 18:10:52.076: I/Process(1874): Sending signal. PID: 1874 SIG: 9
03-23 18:16:35.376: D/gralloc_goldfish(1927): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-23 18:16:41.526: D/AndroidRuntime(1927): Shutting down VM
03-23 18:16:41.526: W/dalvikvm(1927): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a43b90)
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927): Process: com.example.chopbuilderfordrums, PID: 1927
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.chopbuilderfordrums.LaunchEnduranceList }
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3423)
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3384)
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3626)
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3594)
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at com.example.chopbuilderfordrums.ExerciseList.button2Click(ExerciseList.java:32)
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at com.example.chopbuilderfordrums.ExerciseList.onClick(ExerciseList.java:41)
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-23 18:16:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1927):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-23 18:17:48.786: D/gralloc_goldfish(1950): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-23 18:17:51.566: D/dalvikvm(1950): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 57K, 4% free 3235K/3364K, paused 83ms, total 93ms
03-23 18:17:51.676: D/dalvikvm(1950): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 7K, 4% free 3326K/3464K, paused 73ms, total 84ms
03-23 18:17:51.686: I/dalvikvm-heap(1950): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.389MB for 1127536-byte allocation
03-23 18:17:51.776: D/dalvikvm(1950): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 4427K/4568K, paused 84ms, total 85ms
```

Please help me resolve these issues.  I'm brand new!!

Comment: As the exeption says, "No Activity found to handle Intent {act=com.example.chopbuilderfordrums.LaunchEnduranceList" - Do you have a LaunchEnduranceList.java in your project which extends Activity or one of it's subclasses?  Does that have any odd dependencies?  Do you have proguard misconfigured?

Comment: Do you have  `LaunchEnduranceList` defined in your `manifest.xml` correctly? Try `startActivity(new  Intent(ExerciseList.this, LaunchEnduranceList.class));`

Comment: I do have a LaunchEnduranceList.java.  Here is the that:

Comment: You don't need to post that class

Comment: That was it!!  Thanx.  Wasn't stated in my manifest correctly.  I needed to add:

Comment: <activity
                android:name="com.example.chopbuilderfordrums.LaunchEnduranceList"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_launch_endurance_list" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action     android:name="com.example.chopbuilderfordrums.LaunchEnduranceList"     />

                    <category     android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

Comment: I'm glad it's fixed. Please [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964329/eclipse-logcat-debugging/18964524#18964524) about how to read your logcat. It will help tremendously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AndroidRuntime(1874): Shutting down VM 03-23 18:10:48.526:
 W/dalvikvm(1874): threadid=1: thread exiting with 
uncaught exception (group=0xb1a43b90) 
03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874): FATAL EXCEPTION:
 main 03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874): Process: 
com.example.chopbuilderfordrums, 
PID: 1874 03-23 18:10:48.606: E/AndroidRuntime(1874):
```

According to this:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:
     No Activity found to handle Intent 
    { act=com.example.chopbuilderfordrums.LaunchEnduranceList }
```

com.example.chopbuilderfordrums.LaunchEnduranceList  Activity is either:

1. Not declared in the AndroidManifest.xml
2. You haven't created `LaunchEnduranceList` class yet:
    `public class LaunchEnduranceList extends Activity`

Answer (score 2):

are you sure from this

```
com.example.chopbuilderfordrums.LaunchEnduranceList
```

try this and if it give u same exception that's mean u don't have the activity class

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, LaunchEnduranceList.Class));
```